# Sharing memory with concurrent.futures and getting RuntimeError: SynchronizedArray objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance

Tags: python, parallel-processing, large-data

I am looking to parallelise some mote carlo code over a given number of CPUs on my machine that take the same input parameters. Im looking to use shared memory to distribute the data between cores because without doing do my RAM 'explodes' and kills all the processes.

Ive tried using both multiprocessing pool.map as well as concurrent.futures but have found the same issues for both:

I have tried manager.Array() but this leads to significantly slow processing and bottlenecks the code.

Ihave tried multiprocessing.Array but this leads to the following error:

RuntimeError: SynchronizedArray objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance

Edit: I tried using threadpool executor but firstly i had bottlenecked speeds then when i tried setting lock=False i got the memory crash again

Here is the code i use to run my function (new_null):

```
        modulation_factor_12 =multiprocessing.Array('d',modulation_factor_12)
        modulation_factor_3 = multiprocessing.Array('d',modulation_factor_3)
        TIME=multiprocessing.Array('d',TIME)
        TIME_3=multiprocessing.Array('d',TIME_3)
        iterables=np.array(range(cpu_num))
        new_null_concurrent_partial=partial(new_null_concurrent,av_power_norm_real=av_power_norm_real,mod_angles=mod_angles,mod_angles_3=mod_angles_3,modulation_factor_12=modulation_factor_12,modula$


        with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
            futures = {executor.submit(new_null_concurrent_partial, iterable): iterable for iterable in iterables}

            for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
                iterable = futures[future]
                result = future.result()
```

Should i be using a completely different way to parallelise? Im very new to this lol.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Share variable in concurrent.futures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66766457/share-variable-in-concurrent-futures)